# Giant IPKernelApp Error Using Hydrogen in Atom

Tags: ipython, jupyter, atom-editor, hydrogen

Starting a few days ago, after months without issue, I began having a giant error box keep popping up when editing my code in Atom. I believe it is from the Hydrogen plugin, the weird thing is even with this error the code still runs and does what I want it too.

I created a new conda environment, installing only what I needed (pandas, geopandas, descartes, jupyter) and even when using the new environment in Atom I am getting this issue. I've tried upgrading ipykernel but it is already the most recent version.

**Error Message**

> [IPKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg)) File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 762, in run value = future.result() File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 234, in wrapper yielded = ctx_run(next, result) File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 583, in complete_request matches = yield gen.maybe_future(self.do_complete(code, cursor_pos)) File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 360, in do_complete return self._experimental_do_complete(code, cursor_pos) File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 385, in _experimental_do_complete completions = list(_rectify_completions(code, raw_completions)) File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 484, in rectify_completions completions = list(completions) File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 1818, in completions for c in self._completions(text, offset, _timeout=self.jedi_compute_type_timeout/1000): File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 1861, in _completions matched_text, matches, matches_origin, jedi_matches = self._complete( File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 2029, in _complete completions = self._jedi_matches( File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/completer.py", line 1373, in _jedi_matches interpreter = jedi.Interpreter( File "/home/username/anaconda3/envs/fresh/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jedi/api/init.py", line 725, in init super().init(code, environment=environment, TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'column'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest jedi (0.18) release is incompatible with IPython 7.19 see [this discussion](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12740). IPython: 7.20 (released Feb 1st 2020) and 8.0 (not yet released) have a compatibility fix.

The correct workaround at this time is to upgrade IPython:

```
pip install -U ipython==7.20
```

In future you can search for the final two lines of the trackback after removing all path fragments specific to your installation, this is searching for:

```
line 2029, in _complete completions = self._jedi_matches IPython/core/completer.py, line 1373, in _jedi_matches interpreter = jedi.Interpreter( jedi/api/init.py, line 725, in init super().init(code, environment=environment, TypeError: init() got an unexpected keyword argument 'column'
```

This will give you the relevant issues on GitHub in the first two Google result as for today.

Comment: I'm getting this with python 3.6.9, but ipython 7.19 and higher seem to require python 3.7 or higher... Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: Downgrade jedi to 0.17.2